# Spring batch: Item writer is not getting called trough REST call

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a problem with running a job with spring batch via rest call. This is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class DeleteTradeJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;
    
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(DeleteTradeJobConfiguration.class);
    
    /**----------------------------READER--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Trade> tradeDeleteReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[fullPathFileName]}") String pathToFile) {
        log.info("Reader: tradeDeleteReader");
        FlatFileItemReader<Trade> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(pathToFile));

        DefaultLineMapper<Trade> customerLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(";");
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"extid"});

        customerLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        customerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new TradeExtIdFieldSetMapper());
        customerLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();
        reader.setLineMapper(customerLineMapper);
        return reader;
    }
    
    /**----------------------------WRITER--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public DeleteTradeCreditlineItemWriter tradeDeleteWriter() {
        log.info("Writer: tradeDeleteWriter");
        return new DeleteTradeCreditlineItemWriter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Trade> tradeDeleteWriter2() {
        log.info("Writer: tradeDeleteWriter2");
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Trade> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Trade>();

        itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemWriter.setSql("DELETE FROM TRADE WHERE EXT_ID = :extid");
        itemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        itemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

        return itemWriter;
    }
    
    /**----------------------------STEPS---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/
    
    @Bean
    public Step tradeDeleteStep1(@Qualifier("tradeDeleteReader") ItemReader<Trade> tradeDeleteReader) {
        log.info("Step: tradeDeleteStep1");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("tradeDeleteStep1")
                .<Trade, Trade>chunk(15)
                .reader(tradeDeleteReader)
                .writer(tradeDeleteWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step tradeDeleteStep2(@Qualifier("tradeDeleteReader") ItemReader<Trade> tradeDeleteReader) {
        log.info("Step: tradeDeleteStep2");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("tradeDeleteStep2")
                .<Trade, Trade>chunk(15)
                .reader(tradeDeleteReader)
                .writer(tradeDeleteWriter2())
                .build();
    }
    
    /**----------------------------JOBS----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/
    
    @Bean
    public Job tradeDeleteJob(@Qualifier("tradeDeleteReader") ItemReader<Trade> tradeDeleteReader) {
        log.info("Job: tradeDeleteJob");
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("tradeDeleteJob")
                .start(tradeDeleteStep1(tradeDeleteReader))
                .next(tradeDeleteStep2(tradeDeleteReader))
                .build();
    }
    
}
```

and

```
@PostMapping("deleteDealsByFile")
    public MappingJacksonValue deleteDealsByFile(@RequestParam(value="file", required = true) MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        BaseResponse<BatchStatus> result = new BaseResponse<>();
        File file = BatchUtils.createFileFromMultipart(multipartFile);

        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("fullPathFileName", file.getAbsolutePath())
                .addString("fileName", file.getName())
                .addString("JobId", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .addLong("date",System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        
        
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(tradeDeleteJob, jobParameters);
        BatchUtils.deleteFileAfterJob(file);
        BatchStatus response = execution.getStatus();
        
        if (response.equals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED))
            result.setResult(response);
        else if(response.equals(BatchStatus.FAILED)) {
            result.getExecutionInfo().setResultCode(2);
            result.getExecutionInfo().setResultMessage(""+response);
        }
        else {
            result.getExecutionInfo().setResultCode(1);
            result.getExecutionInfo().setResultMessage(""+response);
        }
        
        result.setResult(response);
        return new MappingJacksonValue(result);
    }
```

as you see i have one reader and two writer with @StepScope annotation, but when i call the post no writer is called. I put some logs in the code to debug the flow of the job and the only log that prints is the reader..

I don't know where to turn as most of solutions involves the use of @StepScope both in reader and writers.

Also I added this rows in properties:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false
```

ironically when application start it runs the job and logs both reader and writers :/

Comment: If writer is not called then may be there is no data to read and processed. You can double check if file is not empty before starting batch?

Comment: oh thank you!! for some reason when I read the MultiPartFile it creates a file but it's empty. I solved with FilleOutputStream.

Thanks